# Norton equivalent current

Tags: norton

I calculated the Norton equivalent circuit of a given circuit and I found the result is the same as my book provide, except for the sign.

Here is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqmleim.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the circuit I've to analyse to calculate the Norton current is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVgP7m.png)</sup>

Doing a KCL at the node 1:

\$i_N=-\frac{Av_d}{R}\$

Now, my book says that it's \$i_N=+\frac{Av_d}{R}\$, in fact it draws the current \$i_N\$ in the opposite direction.

My question is: why?

Comment: Because that is conventionally how it is done. When doing Norton equivalent you usually find the output current when load is shorted, which would be the current coming out of the circuit, not in. Logically if you hooked a short circuit load to that output, current would flow in the opposite direction as you have drawn i_N. The real question is why you would draw the current going the way you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a matter of references*.

When you start to tackle the problem you short circuit your port and draw a reference for the Norton current. It's just like saying "this is what positive Norton current is to me".

After solving the circuit you get a result that is negative? No problem: it just means that the current is actually flowing in the opposite way, i.e. out of node 1. Your answer and your book's are just the same: the book says that output current is positive, and gets a positive current that is then going out, while you say that input current is positive, and get a negative current that is then going out.

Note that an answer giving only the current would be incomplete: if I told you that the current flowing in the controlled source is 1A you should ask me: is it going from plus to minus or vice versa?

You can think of an analogy in kinematics: the first thing you do before solving a problem is choosing a reference system*. If you don't choose it and tell your teacher that the ball speed is 10m/s he should yell at you.

*I believe that's the correct English word, please comment if it's not.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the point for a moment. I was just "out of my brain". Thanks again!

Comment: The end of your third paragraph seems confusing. The book says that current flows out and gets a positive answer. OP says the current flows in and gets a negative answer. So their answers agree.

Comment: @I.Wolfe you mean the paragraph containing 'Your answer and your book's are just the same'? It seems quite clear from that to me...

Comment: My book drawed the current in the opposite flow direction and (of course) changed the sign at the current value. I was just confused. Thank you two all!

Comment: I'd say this question should be deleted, because trivial...but it's here...

Comment: You use two different wordings, it is up to interpretation how "output current is positive" and "input is positive" compare. Input as in the output is really an input, or input as in current from the current source? It also seems to contradict your previous statement that it's ok OP got a negative current if you then state that both the book and OP got positive currents. I can understand it fine as is, I'm just used to typing up explanations for the "average joe" and I could see that wording being a source of confusion.

Comment: Ok now I get it, I'll rephrase it.